# Section numbering in article vs. report class

Tags: sectioning, numbering, document-classes, article, report

```
\section{Section title here}}
\subsection*{The subsection without numbers, but want it to appear in TOC}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{The subsection without numbers, but want it to appear in TOC}
```

This is how I am avoiding subsection numbering and only showing section numbering. But I want subsection to appear in ToC so using the line below. All the above I did under `\documentclass{article}` however when I change it to `\documentclass{report}` it started showing up numbers again.

I would appreciate if you can guide me to understand this a bit more.
I can get by with `article`; however, I am interested to know the  difference. 
How can I achieve same in `\documentclass{report}`?

Comment: I've marked your inline code with backticks `\``. (And I've removed your name from the actual post since it shows up in the lower right corner anyway.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let me guess: After the switch from `article` to `report`, your `\subsection` is still unnumbered, but your `\section` suddenly shows up as "0.x A section" (which resembles the look of `\subsection` in `article`)? That is because the `report` class (and the `book` class) feature the additional sectioning level `\chapter`, which becomes the new top level.

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

% Uncomment the following line to get rid of "zero-sections"
% \chapter{Chapter title here}

\section{Section title here}

\subsection*{An unnumbered subsection appearing in the ToC}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{An unnumbered subsection appearing in the ToC}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: If I understand correctly, you want the effect of the following (to be added to the preamble):

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
```

Chapters are still numbered, but sections don't feature the chapter number. (This may confuse readers, and it may screw up the cross-reference mechanism.)

Comment: That is correct, but I don't want it to show the chapter number just show section numbers only.

Comment: thats exactly what I want to add the effect of \renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}, thanks a million

Comment: @Aku Why are you using the report class at all if you want to make it behave like article does by default?

Comment: @Seamus- I wanted it to behave like a report. But did not know how to do it when I was learning TeX, everything I wanted to write worked pretty good with article. Now when I am close to finishing my report I thought I can check here if there is a way to go back. I did not know about this site until recently.

Answer (score 3):

`\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}` will show only Chapter (if applicable) and Section numbers. The subsections will still appear, unnumbered, in the table of contents.

To get the change to appear, you will need to run LaTeX twice

Comment: To quote Kopka and Daly (2004), p. 59: `\section` is always level 1, `\subsection` level 2, [...] [I]n book and report classes, [...] `\chapter` becomes level 0."

Comment: Still it is showing up as 0.xx in the document and as well as in the TOC

Comment: @lockstep yep I fixed that already.

Comment: @Aku That's what it's supposed to do. Using the report means you also have access to the `\chapter` command. So your sections, which appear before the first chapter command will appear as belonging to the 0th chapter.

Comment: @Aku, note also that to effect the changes, you need to run LaTeX twice.