# LyX: reduce spacing in TOC

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, lyx

Is it possible to reduce line spacing in the Table of Contents?

I have tried adding `\singlespacing` before the TOC but I get "Undefined control sequence"

I have also tried `\setlength{\itemsep}{0mm}`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try setting in the preamble `\usepackage{setspace}` and after `\begin{document}` write `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setstretch{0.9}}` (needs Ctrl-L for the TeX mode.

You can decrease the number to any value you need.

Another possibility is to set the additional space to zero:

```
\begingroup
\def\addvspace#1{}
\tableofcontents
\endgroup
```

Comment: This works! However, the spacing between Parts and Sections is still quite big even when setting \setstretch{0}. Can it be decreased any further?

Comment: @user29762: see my edit for another solution

Answer (score 5):

From other posts I guess that you are using the `article` class where the spacing is large.

In contrast, for the `report` class or a similar class like `scrreprt`, the spacing between TOC entries is about single spaced. Hence, one solution (and my suggestion) would be to switch to the `report` class......

(There are some comparisons: [Regarding the `book`, `report`, and `article` document classes: what are the main differences?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36988/book-vs-report-vs-article-document-class) and [Section numbering in article vs. report class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8465/article-vs-report))